# Answer questions on the question main screen

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I would like to be able to answer questions on the main screen of the question itself rather than going into a new screen like in phone.

As tablets have larger screens and browsing from the tablet allows me to answer from the same screen like the Desktop version, I would like to see this feature implemented in the app.

This would be really helpful in explaining every point in a question, also analyzing other answers and adding any relevant data.