# See the question while I am answering

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When I make an answer in the application I cannot see the question. Many questions we need to just make modifications in our answers.

Please let us see and copy parts of the question in the answer editor

Regards

Comment: Why is this the case? Do you often answer without fully reading the question? "See parts of the question"... there is very limited real estate (in general) if you want to see your answer as well as the markdown formatting. And it seems like you're referring specifically to the mobile version (where there is even more limited space). "Copy parts of the question"... which parts?

Comment: In fact my question is android-app tagged. I entered in the application's about option and selected feature request then the application created this question. Yes I need to copy parts of the original code. I of course read the entire question before answering. But then I need to review parts. I feel blindy without this.

Comment: If you mind about the limited space. There is a preview button right? Well they can add a Question button.

Comment: What I need to do now as a workaround is to answer quick then see the question and edit the answer an so on until the answer is complete.  Another workaround I open the question in the browser and switch between browser and the application. Or I finally use just the mobile version in browser which allow write the answer and see the question

Comment: Related/dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247588/answer-questions-on-the-question-main-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press the back button to return to the question. When viewing the question, there is a button at the bottom of the screen which will return you to the draft of your answer.

[image]